# Grant sonarr user read/write/execute permission (recursive) for a mounted share

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mount, virtual-machine

I am on an Ubuntu 20.04 VM. My network share is accessible via credentials and has been tested for write permissions. The issue I believe is the permissions on my VM(Client) device.

The goal is to get arr apps to be able to write to my SMB share where my media library is.

The folder structure is:

```
data
└── media
     ├── books
     ├── movies
     ├── music
     └── tv
```

I have created a mount point at:

```
/data/media
```

Added the following line to /etc/fstab - the mount works and I can view all files in the share, but no writing is allowed by any user other than root.

```
//192.168.0.196/SHARE/jukebox /data/media cifs credentials=/root/smbCredentredentials_sonarr_databarge,uid=129,gid=1004,forceuid,forcegid,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,nounix 0 0
```

The above line went through several iterations, and I eventually just used the noperm option to try it - and again, user sonarr has no access to create folders

```
//192.168.0.196/SHARE/jukebox /data/media cifs credentials=/root/smbCredentredentials_sonarr_databarge,noperm 0 0
```

My local user: sonarr is a member of media_apps

```
user@UbuntuDesktop-VM:/$ id sonarr
uid=129(sonarr) gid=1003(arr) groups=1003(arr),1004(media_apps)
```

I have tried every combination of chown, chmod, opening Nautilus as root user and updating permissions as I can find on the internet. See a few options below:

```
## Try to set ownership
user@UbuntuDesktop-VM:/data$ sudo chown -vR sonarr:media_apps ./media
changed ownership of './media/youtube/let’s subnet your home network _ You SUCK at subnetting _ EP 6.webm' from root:media_apps to sonarr:media_apps

## Set ownership and grant full access to owner
user@UbuntuDesktop-VM:/data$ sudo chown sonarr:media_apps /data/media
[sudo] password for user: 
user@UbuntuDesktop-VM:/data$ sudo chmod g+rwX /data/media -R
user@UbuntuDesktop-VM:/data$
```

All the commands above appeared to have "good output", but when I go to the sonarr shell and cd to the share directory, I can't create a test directory

```
sonarr@UbuntuDesktop-VM:/data/media$ mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘test’: Permission denied
```

Output of `ls -al` below:

```
user@UbuntuDesktop-VM:/data/media$ ls -al
total 21
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   media_apps    0 Mar 13 16:04 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 sonarr media_apps 4096 Mar 13 14:58 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   media_apps 6148 Mar 10 20:26 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   media_apps    0 Mar  6 12:23 eBooks
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   media_apps    0 Oct 17 14:24 movies
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   media_apps    0 Sep 14 08:48 music
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   media_apps    0 Mar 10 20:23 tv
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   media_apps    0 Nov  2 22:23 youtube
```

The user sonarr has no write access to /media or any subfolders. If I `sudo su root`, I can create any directories, files or anything I want to.

Please help I am desperate.

Comment: `chown` or `chmod` over smb mounted volumes won't work (unlexx unix-extensions are involved). Try to change permissions on the server, or try to mount with NFS. The latter supports all commands of a "real" filesystem.